# Create a file in remote linux machine

Tags: perl

I want to create a file in remote Linux machine from my local windows machine.
The file which will be created should be of 10 lines
like

```
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193000|12
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917194000|13
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917195000|14
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917196001|15
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193002|6
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193500|13
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193700|1
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193200|13
```

My code:

```
use Net::SSH2::Simple;
use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2::Simple->new();
$ssh2->connect('host') or die "Unable to connect Host $@ \n";

$ssh2->auth_password('user','password') or die "Unable to login $@ \n";
my $test = <<'END';
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917193000|12
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917194000|13
E-762334|UC5L0001|2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372|3.0.0|20130917195000|14
END

my $cmd="echo $test > /data/spanda/pppp1";
($stdout,$stderr, $exitcode) = $ssh2->cmd($cmd ,'bufsize' => 4_096  ) or die "cannot execute command: ";

if ($exitcode == 0) {  
    print $stdout if $stdout; 
    print $stderr if $stderr;  
} else {           
    print $stderr if $stderr;  
    die "command  failed with exit code $exitcode";     
}
```

I am getting Error like

```
13: Command not found.
E-762334: Command not found.
UC5L0001: Command not found.
2.6.7.1.0.12.0.0.0.372: Command not found.
3.0.0: Command not found.
```

Comment: Why don't you just create the file locally and copy it to the remote machine?

Comment: did you try using `/bin/echo` in place of plain `echo`?

Comment: The errors appear to indicate that the shell is trying to interpret each line in $test as a command.

Comment: @Sue Spence: this is the answer, care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your command doesn't work for the same reason as `echo foo|bar > /tmp/x` doesn't work (strings with pipes should be quoted).

On the other hand there is more robust method; `Net::SSH2::Simple` inherits from [`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH2) which in turn can return [`Net::SSH2::SFTP`](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/Net-SSH2-0.53/lib/Net/SSH2/SFTP.pm) object,

```
  use Fcntl;

  # my $sftp = $ssh2->sftp();
  my $fh = $ssh2->sftp->open('/data/spanda/pppp1', O_WRONLY|O_CREAT) or die;

  print $fh $test;
```

Comment: Thanks Everybody for helping me.